# Invocation of Rest WS using jquery succeeded but with no result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rest

I'm having an issue when invoking a Restful WS with a HTML and javascript web page.

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({ 
               type: "GET",
               dataType: "script",
               crossDomain: true,
               url: "http://localhost:8013/publicationservice/lista",              
               complete: function (xhr) {
                   console.log(xhr);
                   console.log("======");

               },
            });
```

This is how I invoke the service. It returns a readyState: 4, responseCode: 200 and message: "success". But the method of my Rest WS returns a String. The problem is that, when I print "xhr" I get the object data. But when I print the responseText property it says undefined. But whe I debug in both chrome console and firefox firebug, in the "network" tab I see the response with my result as a String (which happens to be a JSON working with JSONP. Why I don't use dataType json or jsonp then? because it gives me an error, but it works fine when I set the datatype to Script). But that's the main problem, I can't get the value of my String which is what I require to finish my application.
I've tried all the possible parameters for the $ajax call, but no success. If anybody can help me, I will really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `success` instead of `complete`.

Comment: I've already tried, when I use success, my xhr returns "undefined", it even not return the object. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into same origin security policy, it seems. Script will load regardless of whether you're loading your web service from the same host or another, but other data types are restricted. Read more about it: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [Cross-origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

One way to solve this is to add CORS headers so that you can retrieve the data using the `json` data type, or even `text`.

Assuming your script runs from `http://www.example.com`, then have the web service on the `localhost:8013` server return the header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com
```

This will let *modern* browsers access your web service cross-origin. Beware that older browsers don't implement this and you shouldn't rely on it.

I'd recommend the alternative below, as long as you have access to change the output of the web service:

Another way is to overcome the same-origin limitation is to change your web service to return *proper* JSONP, which means including either a variable assignment or function call in your web service response. Let's assume your web service means to return `{ "status": "Green", "options": { "alpha": true, "bravo": null } }`, then you'd have it send either:

```
window.var1 = { "status": "Green", "options": { "alpha": true, "bravo": null } }
```

or:

```
callbackFunction( { "status": "Green", "options": { "alpha": true, "bravo": null } }  )
```

In the latter case, you would have to define `callbackFunction()` prior to running the `$.ajax` command. In the former case, you'd end up with a variable polluting your global namespace.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I don't understand well what you're referring to. I have tried the callbackFunction but it didn't work either. :(. I'm very new to this technologies.

Comment: Make your REST WS return data in the format: `callbackFunction( { "status": "Green", "options": { "alpha": true, "bravo": null } }  )`  then create a function above your $.ajax call `window.callbackFunction  = function(data) { console.log(data); }`

Comment: thanks for the response. The problem is that I'm allowed just to modify the html which contains the javascript and jquery. I'm not allowed to modify the rest. For the developments required I've been asked for, the restful ws must return a string with the form of a json. The call to the json used to be something like:
var script = document.create('script');
script.src = "http://server.com/listOfData.js"
document.body.appendChild(script);
I was supposed to change to a restful ws that returns a string. Changes are allowed only in my html. :( Thanks

Comment: sorry for the super long delay... must turn on email notifications from stackoverflow...  If you cannot change the format of the web server's response, and it only returns pure JSON, AND you have to retrieve the data from a different host+port, then it simply will not work. Your old method of dynamically adding a script tag is not subject to the same-origin policy, that's why it worked the old way. If your employer/client is already changing the way their server works, and they DON'T want JSON**P** then they must add the CORS header for it to work. OR serve YOUR script from the same server!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the [dataType](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests) to **script** tells jquery to execute the response as javascript application code which I think is incorrect in your case.

If you are getting errors when you set the dataType to **json**, this is often because the response failed json validation. Some [validators](http://jsonlint.com/) vary in their strictness, for example:

This code fails json validation in some parsers:

```
{
     key : "value"
}
```

Instead, you have to wrap both key and value in quotes like this:

```
{
     "key" : "value"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The problem is that I've already tried with both forms, and with both I'm getting exactly the same. I've heard that there's a $jsonp function in jquery. But I'm lloking for information and I haven't find anything yet. Is there any other way to invoke my rest ws?